# How to check empty array in ionic 5

Tags: javascript

The value of a variable is {}

i am trying to check if its empty or not using if statement.

I have tried the following

```
if(val)
        {
            console.log("NOT EMPTY");
        }
        else
        {
        console.log("EMPTY");
      }
```

But this returns NOT EMPTY, meanwhile the array is empty...please help.i am using IONIC

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Ionic. It is a [basic javascript operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

```
if(Array.isArray(val)) {
  console.log("NOT EMPTY");
} else {
  console.log("EMPTY");
}
```